# JQuery function fn() is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a third party Jquery plugin named `sumoselect.js` in my project .

And inside of it , once my select box is rendered , I appended a div element with an anchor tag within and want to handle a click event.

I did something like :

```
            //## Create New Application Specific code
            createNew: function () {
                var O = this;
                O.optDiv.append($('<ul class="form-control"><li><div style="margin-top:4px;"><a class="ispicon ispicon_plus" style="padding-left:12px;cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addgroup" title="Create New"> Create New</a></div></li></ul>').on('click', handleClick));
            },

            handleClick: function () {
                alert("Oh My");
            },
```

But it says `handleClick` is not defined.

Even putting the function on top of `createNew` throws the same error.

What am I missing ?

Comment: _What am I missing?_ **[mcve]**

Comment: ^^ using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) so it's runnable on-site.

Answer (score 1):

`handleClick` is a function within the object calling it, so you should change it to `this.handleClick`. Example below:

```js
 //## Create New Application Specific code
var foo = {
            createNew: function () {
                $('body').append($('<ul class="form-control"><li><div style="margin-top:4px;"><a class="ispicon ispicon_plus" style="padding-left:12px;cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addgroup" title="Create New"> Create New</a></div></li></ul>').on('click', this.handleClick));
            },

            handleClick: function () {
                alert("Oh My");
            }
  }

foo.createNew();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In the snippet above, you can also use `foo.handleClick` instead of `this.handleClick`. That can be convenient if `this` actually refers to something else (eg. within an event). Or as one of my favourite quotes from [Ben Halpern](https://twitter.com/bendhalpern/status/578925947245633536):

> Sometimes when I'm writing Javascript I want to throw up my hands and
>   say "this is bullshit!" but I can never remember what "this" refers to